# Mac HUD window in Qt

Tags: cocoa, qt

I am trying to create a HUD that is an NSPanel in Qt. I am using QMacCocoaViewContainer as suggested in the qt documentation.

In HUD.h

```
#import <QWidget>
#import <QMacCocoaViewContainer>


class HUD : public QMacCocoaViewContainer
{
public:
    HUD(QWidget* parent);
};
```

In HUD.mm

```
#import "HUD.h"
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

    HUD::HUD(QWidget* parent) : QMacCocoaViewContainer(0,parent)
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSPanel *panel = [[NSPanel alloc] initWithContentRect: NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0,0,250,250))                                     
                                            styleMask:NSHUDWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask | NSUtilityWindowMask                        
                                            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                                            defer:YES   
                                            screen:[[NSApp mainWindow] screen]];

        setCocoaView(panel);


        [panel release];
        [pool release];
    }
```

Every time I run it however I get an error saying [NSPanel window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21231f0. Has anybody had any luck mixing Qt and Cocoa? Any tricks that you used to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this class is supposed to own a view, not a window. An NSPanel is a window, so giving it to something that wants a view is not going to work.

Either create a view and give that to the view container, or use an equivalent class that takes a window.